# How to use cygstart when using run.exe in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'd prefer to use emacs as a shortcut directly by using run.exe, but when I open it that way, I lose access to cygstart when I try to do things like open web links (etc). Is there some way to get around this issue when using run.exe?

Answer (score 0):

append the search path.

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe -p /bin emacs
```

what's magic here is cygwin expands /bin on the commandline into both /bin and /usr/bin in the real PATH environment.